# CURL and ConnectTimeOut , TimeOut

Tags: php, curl

I config :

> curl_setopt($this->ch,
>   CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 15);
>   curl_setopt($this->ch,
>   CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout);

why I get this error

> Maximum execution time of 120 seconds
>   exceeded in xxxx.php at this line:
>
> curl_exec($this->ch);

I use CURL to get a page , login, upload files. send approximate 30 request .( i only use curl_init() once )

Anyone can help me .

Comment: What is the value of `$timeout`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

120 seconds is the maximum execution time for your whole script.

See http://php.net/manual/es/function.set-time-limit.php

Comment: i know this but i confused . , i will check it again

Comment: i confused because there has times , script is work, several is not.

Answer (score 1):

may be you use php5.3.6 on windows maybe it cause by curl_multi_select return -1 and you can set the `rl_multi_select($mh,$multi_select_timeout)`

Answer (score 1):

you can set the  timeout  of the function curl_multi_select from 1.0 to 0.5 or change to linux version